# Загрузка файла PNG, JPEG, PDF с сервера на GWT

Tags: gwt, java

Сценарий:
 1. Пользователь кликает по кнопке "скачать"
 2. Появляется индикатор загрузки
 3. Как только с сервера приходит ответ (выскакивает окно сохранения файла в браузере), выполняем некоторую функцию в GWT

Возможно ли? Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Решение найдено, но не через GWT

ссылка: http://johnculviner.com/post/2012/03/22/Ajax-like-feature-rich-file-downloads-with-jQuery-File-Download.aspx

Суть проста:
 1. используем jquery
 2. добавляем библиотеку которая по ссылке
 3. на сервере при отдаче файла добавляем куку fileDownload=true в случае успеха конечно же
 4. код создаёт невидимый айфрэйм, поэтому вас не перекинет на другую страницу в случае ошибки
 5. по таймауту идёт проверка этого айфрема и выполняются определенные функции :)